# Match 3 or more values in FTS table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, match, fts3

I have 2 **FTS** tables:**search** and **search_eng**. I am trying to get **entry_id** of matched word from **search_eng**. Then I take values from **search** according to those **entry_id**. But when I tried implement that in the way which was shown below it is giving error:**SQL logic error**.
This is because of **MATCH** ing more than 2 values? If not what I am doing wrong?

```
//takes entry_id, g_value where matches word 
        query = "SELECT * FROM search_eng WHERE g_value MATCH '"
                + lookingFor + "' LIMIT 10";
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //if cursor is not empty
            int num = 0;//counter for loop
            query = querySelectFromTableWhere;//"SELECT entry_id AS _id, re_value, ke_value, g_value, pos FROM search WHERE "
            do {
                if (num == 0) {
                    //for the first time
                    //query for getting all data of words which matches with entry_id which was got from search_eng
                    query = query
                            + " entry_id MATCH '"
                            + cursor.getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex("entry_id"))+"'";
                } else {
                    //next tries: 2nd time, 3rd time...
                    //query for getting all data of words which matches with entry_id which was got from search_eng
                    query = query
                            + " OR entry_id MATCH '"
                            + cursor.getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex("entry_id"))+"'";
                }
                num++;//plus counter
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            query=query+" LIMIT 10";
        }
```

**Stacktrace:**

> 09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing
>   database 09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.native_fill_window(Native Method)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:73)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:299)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:272)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getCount(CursorAdapter.java:202)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:489) 09-26
>   21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):    at
>   com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity.displayListView(MainActivity.java:147)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:136)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity$1.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:122)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6603) 09-26
>   21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):    at
>   android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:6650) 09-26
>   21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):    at
>   android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:6794)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:889)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:654)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:180)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:120)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:283)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:79)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-26
>   21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 09-26 21:48:14.937:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 09-26
>   21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-26
>   21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 09-26 21:48:14.937:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   09-26 21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625) 09-26
>   21:48:14.937: E/AndroidRuntime(29495):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Are you implying that other queries work?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer `sqlite` documentation [here](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/fts3.html#section_3).

To match multiple words, you have to add `OR` between words, not `MATCH`es. Something like:

```
SELECT entry_id AS _id, re_value, ke_value, g_value, pos
FROM search
WHERE entry_id MATCH 'firstWord OR secondWord`
```

Yes, OR is inside `''`.